# Angular2 What concept should I be using if I want to restrict some component to certain users.

Tags: angular, authentication

This is just question to ask what concept of angular2 should I be using coz once I know what concepts to use, I could study them .

So I have five different user types : admin, guest, teacher, student, parent.

I have many components and few of them are restricted to parent, parent, and admin; Some others are open to all; some are only for teacher .. etc.

Which concept should I be using? ngSwitch/Authguard..?

I appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: guards . . . . . . .

Answer (score 0):

Guards are specially implemented for such kind of usage.
Have a look at the blog
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html
This are the 4 kinds of Guards.

CanActivate - Decides if a route can be activated

CanActivateChild - Decides if children routes of a route can be activated

CanDeactivate - Decides if a route can be deactivated

CanLoad - Decides if a module can be loaded lazily

Practical Example :
http://www.sparkbit.pl/angular-2-route-guards-real-life-example/